# Is this a correct usage of "wait on"?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

I've written the following phrase in a technical document:

> ... the Task is exposed, so it can be waited on

In this context (.NET development), Task is an object instance, and by "waiting on" it, I mean invoking its `Wait` method, so the execution thread pauses until the task is finished.

Is this correct, given the specific context? Is there a better construct?

---

*Update based on answers/comments received so far:*

Essentially, what I mean to say is:

> ... the Task is exposed, so the caller can wait for it to complete by invoking its `Wait()` method

...but without the redundancy, and using the method name as the verb.

Answer (score 3):

"Wait on" is a recognised phrase, but outside IT it usually has the specific meaning of "being attentive to somebody", as in a waiter.

For the sense you mean, "waiting for" is much more common.

However, in programming "wait on" may be regarded as a technical term, meaning "wait until some resource becomes available". I'm not clear from your explanation whether you mean this, or the converse.

Comment: Indeed, the documentation for the `Task.Wait` method says "Waits for the Task to complete execution.". Considering that, would it be ok to construct the phrase in the way I described?

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon: It doesn't sound like your usage is standard in the IT context, so I would strongly advise *not* using it. You'd be much safer using the phrasing commonly used by others - for example, *"...so it can enter [or 'be placed in'] a 'wait' state"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: it's not the task that enters in the "wait" state, but the current thread.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon: I never said anything about whether "it" is a thread within a multi-thread process, or a "task". But that makes no difference anyway. If you think the distinction is important, by all means write "the current thread" rather than "it". Just don't say "it" (or whatever) can be "waited on" if you want the meaning to be clear.

Comment: It sounds to me as if it were written by some American who uses *wait on* rather than *wait for* (I know this construction is present in some American dialects). You should use *waited for,* or @FumbleFingers' excellent suggestion of *placed in a wait state,* since this will be understood by everybody. I don't believe *wait on* is a technical term in programming.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Absolutely. OP says in his first line that *he* wrote this in some technical documentation, and presumably he's come here because he's [quite rightly] uncertain if it's a valid phrasing. To me, "waited on" primarily evokes thoughts of a *person*, being "waited on hand and foot". A slightly bizarre expression, but commonly used in my area.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and Peter: you both have good points. Maybe I should just use "...so it can be awaited", which is more commonly used, although it might have a slightly different connotation.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon: No, no, *no!*. You seem determined not to use standard programming terminology. "Waited on" and "awaited" are *not* normally used in relation to "wait states". I suggest you may be better off asking this question on programmers.se

Comment: @FumbleFingers: considering there's an `await` keyword in C# 5, which takes a `Task` (that would be "to await a Task"), how would you put that in the present perfect? Wouldn't it be "the task has been awaited"?

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon: I don't think we're getting anywhere. You should ask this on programmers.se, rather than dispute usages here with people who mostly aren't programmers.

Comment: @Diego: see the [Task documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct, given the specific context? No, not really, due to the meaning of "waited on" which other users have already explained.
>
> Is there a better construct?

Here are several:

> the Task is exposed, so the `Wait()` method can be used.
> the Task is exposed, so the caller can wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

To *wait on* is to *attend to* someone, or to *serve* someone, so it’s a big no. You typically *wait **for*** something or someone.

Comment: In some American dialects, you *wait on*, and not *wait for.* However, standard English uses *wait for,* and I would recommend using this construction for general audiences, as everybody will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

For the best answer to this question, I suggest you ask somebody who has good command of English and who is also familiar with the type of technical documentation you are writing.

Otherwise, there are too many 'ifs and buts'.

Alternatively, you could formulate a sentence using language closer to that that you are using to describe the meaning of the phrase.

You might come up with something along the lines of:

The Task is exposed, so its Wait method has been invoked.

Comment: Well, I *am* hoping to find some fellow developers from Stackoverflow that spend their free time here :-)

Comment: @Diego: Why not ask there? By limiting the number of people here who can help you, you're not creating a good question

Comment: @simchona: because the answer is about *English usage in relation with a programming concept*, not programming. But I might ask in programmers.se

Comment: @Diego: You specifically stated that you want SO members to help. Why don't you ask them? This question has no potential use to anyone other than yourself.